# How to manage array/arraylist of queues/LinkedLists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I realize that Queue is an interface. My problem is this. I have a Queue initialized as a LinkedList for each day of a month (31) and I need to arrange them. I am having issues understanding issues with generics. My first idea is to either make an Array of Queues (java doesn't seem to like this). Or should I just make an ArrayList of type Queue and make the initial size 32?

If I do that, how would I reference a specific Queue to add something to it? Like this?:

For this I'll say I'm trying to add someone to the list for the 17th day.

```
    ArrayList<Queue<Passenger>> lists = new ArrayList<Queue<Passenger>>(32);
    Passenger person = new Passenger(first, last);
    (lists.get(17)).add(person);
```

I feel like this would give me a null pointer exception? Perhaps not. Any input/example code is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? And why do you want to put a Queue in an Arraylist?

Comment: More context would help.

Comment: Well I have to have 31 of these queues/linkedlists, and I'd rather not have to declare 31 of them individually. I figured an array/arraylist would be better.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor for array list that takes a number determines the initial capacity of the list, not it's size.

Thus when you do:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(32);
System.out.println(list.size()); // prints 0!
```

Instead, initialize your list by adding objects to it:

```
// note that passing 32 here is just an optimization; it tells the list that
// we plan to add 32 elements so that it can pre-allocate the appropriate amount
// of space. We could just as easily have done new ArrayList<Queue<Passenger>>()
List<Queue<Passenger>> queues = new ArrayList<Queue<Passenger>>(32);
for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    queues.add(new LinkedList<Passenger>());
}

// now this will work
queues.get(17).add(person);
```

Comment: So I simply must add placeholder LinkedLists until they need to be used, correct?

Comment: @coltsfan95: yes, if you want to use ArrayList. Alternatively, you could use a Map<Integer, Queue<Passenger>> and initialize each list as you need it. However, the list approach is likely simpler.

Comment: Now it does not let me use .get(i) once I use .get to get a LL out of the arrayList. It says the method is undefined. It does let me add, for some reason.